# How to get the QQuaternion from two QVector3Ds using Qt?

Tags: qt, rotation, qvector

I have two given vectors and I must calculate the quanternion for the rotation between them.

Is this the right way:

```
QVector3D vec1 = QVector3D(0.0,0.0,1.0);
QVector3D vec2 = QVector3D(1.0,0.0,0.0);

QQuaternion quatRot, quat1, quat2;

quat1.setVector(vec1);
quat1.setScalar(0.0);
quat2.setVector(vec2);
quat2.setScalar(0.0);

quatRot = QQuaternion::nlerp(quat1, quat2, 0.5);   //is 0.5 for t correct?

quat2 = quat2.normalized();


QMatrix4x4 rotMat;

rotMat.setToIdentity();
rotMat.rotate(quatRot);
```

And the rotMat is now the roational-matrix that I can use to rotate OpenGL-Objects.
Is that correct?